# Hyperlink to File from Echo'ed value in a form

Tags: php, html, forms, hyperlink, echo

I am trying to hyperlink to a file saved on my server. 
The file gets uploaded using an upload form. 
Once Uploaded, a record is created in my document table with the file name.

One another form, I echo all information relating to this particular entry. some of the fields are editable, and others remain read-only.

I am trying to have the field that echo's the fie location be displayed as a link from which you can open the file. All my fields are echoing correctly, but I just can't seem to get this photo field to hyperlink.

What is the best way to do this?
Here is my code for this part of the form:

```
<input id="photo_input_file" class="form-control1" type="text" placeholder="Photo Verification Missing" value="<a href='http://localhost/scrm/photos/<?php echo $photo_file;?>'>">
```

Comment: you can simply put only link instead of input

Comment: You should not offer direct access to physical files this way. Instead use a "router script" (php script) which accepts the files name or relative path as an argument and then delivers the files content along with the correct http headers. That way you stay in control and can implement things like access control.

Comment: directly display the value in text field(value=`URL`) then write a function or display a button on click go to that url